# Making a super-eutectic

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, solubility, melting-point

A [eutectic system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eutectic_system) is a mixture of substances which has a lower melting point than any of it's components. For example salt to melt ice. Also, a eutectic has the right mixture of components so that it freezes all at once (the [liquidus and solidus](https://blog.lucasmilhaupt.com/en-us/about/blog/liquidus-and-solidus) temperatures are the same).

It seems that the eutectic effect generally grows stronger when we mix three components instead of two. For example [in a magma chamber](https://serc.carleton.edu/research_education/equilibria/ternary_diagrams.html).

If we blend more and more components, how much further can we take this effect? Could we have room temperature inorganic halide salts? An alloy with over a dozen metals liquid below -100C?

Comment: Well, it can get pretty far, but I think that results of adding more components are somewhat diminishing.

Comment: @Mithron: Has anyone tried alloying all the alkali metals and alkaline earth metals together? Start with CsNaK and slowly add in other metals to chip away at the solidus temperature?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium%E2%80%93potassium_alloy#Further_alloys_with_low_melting_points only goes as far as CsNaK

Comment: @Mithron: Why hasn't anyone tried adding lithium or rubidium to CsNaK to see if they can get any lower?

Comment: IIRC alloys of more than 3 elements are still pretty fresh research topic, go for it if you dare ;D

Comment: @Mithoron: I may ask CodysLab. Since partial freezing of a non-eutectic tends to pull things toward eutectic it makes the experiments less picky about exact proportions, which is a must when there are like 6 metals at once.

Comment: related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood%27s_metal#Related_alloys

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.3103/S1062873807050139

Comment: See Wikipedia for molten salts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molten_salt , but even ethylammonium nitrate (q.v.) will only get you to 10°C m.p. BTW, triple-eutectic galinstan, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galinstan, is useful, since it's *much* safer than NaK or Hg. (I remember when aircraft and race car valves used NaK for cooling...)

Comment: The ASM ( American Society for  Metals) has a phase diagram handbook with many three component systems .

Answer (score 6):

This is a quite broad question, and I will try to keep at a reasonably high level. Undoubtedly there are specific systems (more below) that will have unusual features that differ from this outline.

Lets look solely at the liquid phases of mixtures. To zeroth order, one treats a random (unordered) phase as an ideal gas - no atom-to-atom interaction (attractive or repulsive) contributing to the enthalpy, and the entropy comes from random mixing of the A and B atoms. This entropy term ends up being

-RT($x_{A}\ln x_{A} + x_{B} \ln x_{B}$)

with $x_{A} + x_{B} = 1$ and is a maximum when $x_{A} = x_{B} = 1/2$.

The first order treatment of solutions adds an enthalpy of mixing term $\Omega$, the heat of mixing. This comes from considering the energetics of A-A, B-B, and A-B interactions. So, the adjustment to the enthalpy takes on the form

$\Delta H_{mix} = x_{A}x_{B}\Omega$

If the A-B interactions are stronger than the A-A and B-B interactions, the heat of mixing is negative and eutectic may form. A positive heat of mixing leads to miscibility gaps. Again, the enthalpy of mixing takes on a maximum at $x_{A} = x_{B} = 1/2$ for a regular solution, being $0.25\Omega$.

Now, real alloys tend to be non-ideal and non-regular, but lets stay up at 30,000 feet for now.

An extension of the entropy of mixing to ternary solutions is straightforward, looking like

-RT($x_{A}\ln x_{A} + x_{B} \ln x_{B} + x_{C} \ln x_{C}$)

with $x_{A} + x_{B} + x_{C} = 1$, and is a maximum when all compositions are $1/3$.

The enthalpy term gets a bit trickier, since you have to consider A-A, B-B, C-C, A-B, A-C, B-C, as well as A-B-C interactions. So one can write:

$\Delta H_{mix} = x_{A}x_{B}\Omega_{AB} + x_{A}x_{C}\Omega_{AC} + x_{B}x_{C}\Omega_{BC} + x_{A}x_{B}x_{C}\Omega_{ABC}$

As you add more components to the mixture, you need to add more interaction terms.

OK, where are we now? First, the entropy term increases (is increasing negative) as the number of components in the solution increases. For 2 components, the natural log terms come to $-0.69$, for a ternary it is $-1.09$, and for 10 components in equal proportions it is $-2.30$. Not too surprising, the more components the higher the possible entropy.

On the enthalpy side, things look pretty good as well initially. Lets ignore the ternary interaction terms like $\Omega_{ABC}$. Still one is left with more interaction terms that could add up to something. If $\Omega_{AB} = \Omega_{AC} = \Omega_{BC}$ (and all are negative) then the enthalpy of mixing is ${1 \over 3} \Omega$, which is larger than the enthalpy of mixing of the binary solution. As the number of components increases, one goes from $0.25$ for a binary to $0.33$ for a ternary to $0.45$ for a 10-component system. Wow, we win on both counts!

Well, except that it would be highly unlikely that $\Omega_{AB} = \Omega_{AC} = \Omega_{BC}$ (and even less likely as the number of components increases). If the A-B term is more negative than A-C or B-C, then the lowest enthalpy of mixing is found away from the equal 1/3 compositions, so the entropy term is no longer minimized. If the D-E term in a 5-component system is highly positive, that skews things even worse.

As one example, lets look a bit at the Galinstan alloy mentioned in comments. In the Ga-In system, modeling (Ch. Li et al, J. Phase Equilibria 21(4) 357 (2000)) indicates that the enthalpy of mixing term is actually positive - the Ga-In (small) eutectic is driven mainly by the entropy term. For Ga-Sn (Bhupendra Kumar et al., Metals 2021 (11) 1363), the mixing term is also positive. Again, the small eutectic is from the entropy. For In-Sn (X.J. Liu et al., J. Electronic Materials 30(9) 1093 (2001)), the enthalpy term is indeed negative, but fairly small. Why does Galinstan melt "so" low? Well, it is mostly gallium so melts pretty low already, the Ga-In and Ga-Sn eutectics are way over by Ga to begin with, so a bit of both helps add more entropy, and the In-Sn negative enthalpy of mixing adds to that effect.

Could there be better systems? Perhaps, but all the stars have to align with respect to the enthalpy of mixing terms.

Added mostly as a comment, but a paper hot off the press ([Journal of Phase Equilibria and Diffusion](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11669-022-01003-1)) might be interesting. The point is to try and use the Calphad method to rapidly find possible eutectic points in a quaternary system. To quote the abstract:

> In
> multicomponent systems, finding eutectic points can be
> challenging due to the complexity of the systems...

Comment: There is debate whether Galinstan melts at 11C (only 19C below Ga) or -19C (49C reduction).