# Eutectic temperatures of multicomponent metal carbides

Tags: alloy, eutectic

Some carbides do not melt at atmospheric pressure. At high enough temperature, metallic element is in vapor phase. Experimentation with these systems is complicated because of their high melting or sublimation temperatures. For this reason, not much data is available.

Is it possible to mix multiple metal carbides in proportions, which bring the melting point to significantly lower values? How low can it get, assuming the liquid phase contains at least 30 atomic percent carbon and no other non-metals?

How tight lower limit can be found for this (probably never observed) temperature by calculations?

Which metals are likely to comprise the mix in highest concentrations?

Since this is a complicated unsolved problem, partially answering it would be acceptable.

Comment: After perusing the many papers on thermodynamics of binary/ternary systems, I'm just not seeing any. One thing to note is the many different carbide phases that exist, often making it hard to actually have a mixed-metal carbide pseudobinary of a single phase in the first place (which is how I interpret your question). The few that I've found tend to have fairly small terms for the mixing of the metal components.

Comment: @JonCuster Your interpretation seems to forget the possibility that some (pseudobinary) eutectic mixtures may solidify into two phases instead of single solid phase.  I am not sure I used the term 'eutectic' correctly in my original question. I meant whatever liquid phase with metals and at least 30 atom % carbon.

Comment: Ah, OK, you are looking for any cut across a ternary (keeping $x_{C} > 30 at. %) that shows a lower-than-expected liquidus? I'll keep looking then. However, that would really require a very high enthalpy of mixing in the liquid phase to drop the liquid below the tie-line between two usually quite stable carbides (or metal + metal carbide).

Comment: @JonCuster This holds true as long as we hope ternary is enough to get an idea about the general multicomponent behavior. My intuition is, that for more different metals simultaneously present, heat capacity may be higher at temperatures comparable to the melting point of Lithium Acetylide. Am I wrong? I don't fully understand, why the enthalpy of mixing is relevant rather than entropy.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/168754/making-a-super-eutectic/168772#168772 has some perspectives (full disclosure - my answer). From a different direction: the carbides being stable to high temperatures means they already beat out whatever entropy of mixing happens in the liquid. Now, weird things happen in associate liquid models, to be sure. But I'll keep looking around - just haven't found a clear example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had initially approached this from the perspective of a pseudo-binary system on a tie line between two metal carbides of the same crystal structure. One example would be across the $\ce{(Hf,Zr)C_{1-x}}$ line - that carbide show mutual solid solubility across the whole compositional range. And it shows no unexpected deviations from the melting temperature. There are several other ternary systems available in the literature that are similar. As noted in the comments, I was interpreting the question incorrectly, but at least I ruled out a number of known systems.

The other answer mentions $\ce{Li2C2}$, and the C-Li binary system looks like:

[image: C-Li phase diagram]

One sees the very sharp drop in melt temperature right around the 50:50 composition. The crystal structure of the $\ce{Li2C2}$ phase is a body-centered orthorhombic cell with 8 atoms, fairly unusual for most carbides. Unfortunately, there are no C-Li-Metal ternary systems listed at the ASM Alloy Phase Diagram reference site ([ASM International](https://matdata.asminternational.org/apd/index.aspx)) to see if there is any odd behavior with other carbides.

A perusal of available ternary carbide systems does not pull up much either, which is fairly frustrating. So, instead I will suggest a possible system, and explain why it could be interesting.

The first thing to note is that many carbide phases (particularly in the transition metals) have the carbon sitting on interstitial sites in a metal, and for many systems this ends up making the composition either 50:50 or with less carbon than metal. The rare earths are different, with phases like $\ce{PrC2}$ or $\ce{Pr2C3}$. There is usually a eutectic between these carbides and the rare earth metal itself, but the depth (Ce, Dy, La, Nd, Pr) is perhaps 500K at most, and is of course at lower carbon content than the carbides.

In contrast, the Be-C system looks like:

[image: Be-C phase diagram]

Here the eutectic is between the $\ce{Be2C}$ carbide and carbon, with a depth of some 600K or so. So now one looks at Be phase diagrams with carbide-forming metals. It turns out that zirconium is an interesting candidate. First, the Be-Zr system looks like:

[image: Be-Zr phase diagram]

Here there is a surprisingly deep eutectic between the Be-rich compounds and Zr metal, some 800K to 1000K from the melting points of either pure metal.

Then, the C-Zr diagram looks like:

[image: C-Zr phase diagram]

Now, this has a small eutectic between the carbide and carbon of only some 500K or so, but still not bad compared with other carbide phase diagrams.

Now, looking at the carbide phases we see that the $\ce{Be2C}$ crystal structure is of the $\ce{Ca2F}$ structure, while ZrC$_{1-x}$ is the NaCl structure. It is difficult to imagine that one could go smoothly between the two to have complete solid solubility between them.

Anyway, should there not be mutual solubility in the carbide phases, and should there not be a ternary phase that is not exhibited on any of the binary diagrams, one is left with the possibility to traverse the ternary diagram from $\ce{Be2C}$ to ZrC$_{1-x}$ through liquids that, on the binary sides, have fairly steep eutectics relative to the other phases.

Sadly, the Be-C-Zr ternary system has no data that I can find. So this is only a potentially intriguing candidate for the OP.

Comment: Nice to see different approaches to this intriguing problem. As someone with very little experience with phase diagrams, I was thinking about this very differently: First, find metals that have moderately stronger affinity to carbon atom than graphite itself (Be,Mg,Al,Sc,Y). Secondly, add non-carbide-forming metals (Cu,Zn,Ga,Sn...) until solubility of carbon in the melt drops to 30 atom%. Transition metals, if any, may be present only in concentration below percolation threshold. I was hoping to see large thermal expansion and low melting point. Sadly, no data.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be what you bargained for, but [lithium carbide, $\ce{Li2C2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_carbide) alone melts at only 452°C. Melting is promoted by weaker bonding than would be obtained with most metal carbides, which in turn comes fundamentally from lithium having only one valence electron to contribute to such bonds. Lithium also forms small ion pairs or clusters readily, which is also compatible with liquefication.

Comment: It is a good starting point. I was not aware of this before. I'm curious if it forms any pseudobinaries with other carbides.

Comment: @PaulKolk - Given the rather odd phase of Li2C2, I'm not sure there are other metal carbides to have a pseudobinary with.

Comment: @JonCuster What reaction prevents this typically, if we add another acetylide? Calcium acetylide for example. Or are You saying they are just immiscible?

Comment: @PaulKolk - None of the 'standard' carbides I know (say across the transition metals) have that crystal "structure" (used loosely because appartently Li2C2 is hard to crystalize in the first place). The C-Ca binary diagram at the Alloy Phase Diagram Database (https://matdata.asminternational.org/apd/index.aspx) shows only a CaC2 line compound.

Comment: Some of the issues with Li2C2 are covered in S.-M. Liang et al., Journal of Alloys and Compounds 698 (2017) 743-753 "Key experiments and challenging thermodynamic modeling of the Li-Si-C system". For example, they see no solubility between Li2C2 and SiC.